# Installing Linux Ubuntu 19.10 on Asus n550jk with windows 10

Tags: 19.10

I'm trying to installi Ubuntu 19.10 by following these steps:

1. I downloaded the Ubuntu iso and i created a partition by using windows disk management;
2. I created a bootable USB by using universal usb installer;
3. I rebooted my PC by using the UEFI firmware settings (maybe this is the only way to access to the BIOS with an asus laptop);
4. I ordered the boot peripherals: first USB, but the settings are not saved thus I changed three settings. (i) secure boot control: disables; (ii) fast boot: disabled; (iii) launch CSM: enabled. Now I am able to put first USB.
5. There are two USB options in the BIOS' boot: (i) [UEFI: "USB brand's name"]; (ii) ["USB brand's name"]. If I put (i) as first, nothing happens, namely windows 10 is run. If I put (ii) as first, I am able to run the Ubuntu's live version, but there are other two problems: (i) there is a message which says that on my laptop there is not an operative system (neverthless there is windows 10); (ii) when I try to install ubuntu in the free space which I allocated at point (1), this message is showed:

"The Partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as a Reserved BIOS boot area and should be at least 1MB in size..."

Online I read that this error is due to the fact that I didn't use [UEFI:...] as first choice in the BIOS' boot, but, as I said, the [UEFI:...] option does not work.

Can you help me to overcome these stressful problems please?

---

EDIT

Premises: (i) if secure boot is enabled, I cannot enable launch CSM; (ii) when launch CSM is enabled, there is also the option launch PSE OpROM policy.

The trials I did are the following (notations: sb=secure boot; fb=fast boot; CSM=launch CSM; PXE=launch PSE OpROM policy; e=enabled; d=disabled):

1. sb=fb=CSM: d (all options disabled); in this case, after rebooting, there is [UEFI..]. I put it as first choice in the BIOS's boot, but the result is that windows is run, not the USB.
2. sb: d and CSM: e and PXE: d; result: see (1) and morover there is the option ['USB name'] concerning the non UEFI mode.
3. sb: d and CSM=PXE: e; result: see (2).
4. sb=fb: e and CSM: d; result: see (1). These are the default settings.
5. sb: e and fb=CSM: d; result: see (1).
6. sb=fb: d and CSM: e; result: see (2).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Disable "Launch CSM"

Comment: Hello @Pilot6, I setted Launch CSM: disabled, then I reboot (I saved the changes), and I found in the BIOS only the option [UEFI:..]. I put this as first, and then I saved the change. There is still the same problem: my asus laptop does not run the usb, but windows 10.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/857117/what-is-csm-option

Comment: Hello @K7AAY, thank you for the suggestion. Now I knot that I have to disable CSM option, but the USB is not ran when I put it as first choice in the BIOS boot.

Comment: Hi Gennaro, does the USB show in any other case?

Comment: Hello @LuisAlvarado, i'm sorry, but didn't get your answer. The only information that I can add is that the USB works on an other laptop. Can you formulate your answer by using other words please?

Comment: Hi @GennaroArguzzi, does the Live Ubuntu installed in the USB Drive (Flash Drive, Pen Drive), show for the BIOS if you for example, disable CSM, UEFI, Secure Boot or something in the BIOS/UEFI that will make the Ubuntu USB version bootable on your PC.

Comment: Hi @LuisAlvarado, I tried all possible combinations of the options; see the edit please.